# Wordpress Disable Plugin on Specific Pages/Posts

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Does anyone know a really effective method for disabling a plugin (that is active) on a specific page? There are some plugins that are not really needed in some pages of the website and they have lot of CSS and JavaScript files that are slowing the loading speed of the website and sometimes might conflict with other files.

I know that I can mess with the plugin's code etc. but it's not really effective.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Multisite options here: [wp-load Without Loading the plugins](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/283281/wp-load-without-loading-the-plugins/283296#283296)

Answer (score 29):

[Here is the idea](http://lowgravity.pl/blog/quick-tip-how-to-disable-wp-plugin-on-certain-page/).

```
 add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'lg_disable_cart66_plugin' );

 function lg_disable_cart66_plugin($plugins){

      if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/store/') === FALSE && !is_admin() ) {
         $key = array_search( 'cart66/cart66.php' , $plugins );
         if ( false !== $key ) unset( $plugins[$key] );
      }

     return $plugins;
 }
```

p.s. Some [people say](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99047/option-active-plugins-filter-not-working) you might need to put this in `mu-plugins` folder.

Comment: Nice, gives you an understanding of how the "Plugin Organizer" plugin mentioned by @Jesse B works.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, really clean and requires just a small piece of code. IMO installing a plugin like plugin organizer is overkill compared to this neat solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I found this solution also [here](https://kinsta.com/blog/disable-wordpress-plugins/) But this doesn't prevent the plugin from enqueueing all its scripts and styles. I tried this method deactivating Divi Builder Plugin, which adds loads of scripts to the page, but I just need it on certain occasions.Also didn't work with Contact Form 7. Any help?

Comment: Once again, everybody, please pay attention that this code should be put into `mu-plugins` not theme's `functions.php`.

Comment: Thank you this worked for me after trying so many other options. I tried plugin organizer with no luck. This was simple. Create a new php file with this code (name it anything) and add it to your wp-content/mu-plugins directory. Make sure to update cart66 with whatever plugin you are trying to disable also.

Comment: Could you please add more information about this 'trick'. You have now just copied a code from an external page, but what does the code? Where do you add the code? What I read from the code, is that it only runs on the /store/ page and not on the other pages. I am not sure if this answers the related question. People, please be more critical with upvotes, this is not the way we answer questions.

Comment: what I noticed (wordpress 5.1) is that the code will directly disable the plugin without re-enabling it again

Comment: @mainpart how can I disable plugin for specific template? like in content-single-product.php

Comment: @KhushbuVaghela maybe i'm too late for the party but  plugins are starting to load very prior to theme processing. So the only one way to choose what plugin to load and what not to, is to hook as described above to `mu-plugin` folder at startup and get an option `get_option("template")`, compare to some value and decide what to skip

Answer (score 8):

I know it's old but this thread was exactly what I needed.

The only caveat to numediaweb's answer is that remove action requires the same priority as the add action

**Hooks in the plugin**

```
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'easy_fancybox_enqueue_styles', 999);
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'easy_fancybox_enqueue_scripts', 999);
add_action('wp_head', 'easy_fancybox', 999);
```

**Code to remove hooks**

```
function remove_easy_fancybox() {

     global $post;
     $ids = array(12,34,55);
     if(in_array($post->ID,$ids)):
          remove_action('wp_print_styles', 'easy_fancybox_enqueue_styles', 999);
          remove_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'easy_fancybox_enqueue_scripts',999);
          remove_action('wp_head', 'easy_fancybox', 999);

          wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery.fancybox' );
          wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery.easing' );
          wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery.mousewheel' );
          wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery.metadata' );
     endif;
}

add_action('wp_head', 'remove_easy_fancybox', 1);
```

From http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action

> **Important:** To remove a hook, the $function_to_remove and $priority arguments must match when the hook was added. This goes for both
>   filters and actions. No warning will be given on removal failure.

I've included my if statement to only run the action on specific post ids, thought it might be helpful.

Comment: This worked magically for me in a situation in where I needed to remove a plugins functionality from anything that was a page, using `is_page()`.

Answer (score 4):

First check, if the plugin you want to remove doesn't have an option menu where you set pages to exclude.

Second is, look for your plugin action hooks for ex:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'easy_fancybox', 999);
```

This is an example from easy fancybox plugin that hooks to wordpress header. To remove it, I placed this function in your `functions.php` and before any instance of `wp_head();` is called:

```
function remove_easy_fancybox() {

     remove_action('wp_head', 'easy_fancybox_enqueue_styles');
     remove_action('wp_head', 'easy_fancybox_enqueue_scripts');
     remove_action('wp_head', 'easy_fancybox');

     wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery.fancybox' );
     wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery.easing' );
     wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery.mousewheel' );
     wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery.metadata' );
}

add_action('wp_head', 'remove_easy_fancybox', 1);
```

Comment: What to do when you find something like `add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array(&$this, 'plugins_loaded') );`? I prefer to use mainpart's approach (see below).

Answer (score 3):

you can now use the free plugin Freesoul Deactivate Plugins to deactivate specific plugins on specific pages, posts, custom posts and archives, the settings page is really simple

Comment: This is a coding site, not how to install a plugin. Be aware that most plugins bring a lot of more extra code than you initially want. So no.

Comment: A plugin is made by code and not all plugins load a lot of more extra code. If someone else has already solved this problem and written a plugin, it would be not so stupid to use that plugin. Here you have the official WordPress smoke tests of Freesoul Deactivate Plugins: https://plugintests.com/plugins/freesoul-deactivate-plugins/latest. As you will see, the plugin adds 4.42kB of memory usage on front-end (nothing) and an additional loading time that is not measurable (negative in the test). The plugin was created to increase the performance when many plugins are active, not to decrease it.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using this plugin. For me, it was the perfect solution to stop a plugin from loading on a page that it was causing issues on.

Comment: You are welcome! I'm happy it was useful to solve the issue.

Comment: @Jose I just tried out your plugin after trying 2 others. Yours works great!! Thanks!! I'm trying to clean up a site with a ton of plugins, building out a new blog/posts and yours works to disable any of the plugins per page/post.

Comment: @kaplan Thank you very much! I'm happy you find it useful.