# How to turn off wordpress plugin on only certain page?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Hello I have two Wordpress plugins. One plugin is  page-animations-and-transitions . This plugin creates content fly-in animation. Second plugin is wp-catalogue-pro, which creates my products page.

What I need that page-animation-and-transitions plugin do not work in my products page created by other plugin, wp-catalogue-pro.

Could anyone help me with that question?

I tried this solution: [Wordpress Disable Plugin on Specific Pages/Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774424/wordpress-disable-plugin-on-specific-pages-posts)

But I'm not good in coding so it does not work for me.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a place to discuss code. You may want to hire a web developer to help you with this.

Answer (score 2):

When the plugin activated **add_action** will be called.
So, for remove that plugin you have to call **remove_action** on which page you not want it.
**OR**
Look in this plugin which will help you.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-organizer/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-plugins/installation/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the 'remove_action' mentioned above, you can edit the plugin (not always advised) to add

```
if (!is_page('slug'))
```

to wrap the add_action call. For more than one page, do an array.