# How to PREVENT a plugin to run on a SPECIFIC PAGE?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, shortcode, contact-form-7

I am looking for a solution that will NOT activate a certain plugin on a SINGLE PAGE.

I have tried to play around with the attached code (offered by @Kamil Grzegorczyk on [Wordpress Disable Plugin on Specific Pages/Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774424/wordpress-disable-plugin-on-specific-pages-posts)) but with no success.

```
add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'lg_disable_cart66_plugin' );

 function lg_disable_cart66_plugin($plugins){

      if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/store/') === FALSE AND strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/wp-admin/') === FALSE) {
         $key = array_search( 'cart66/cart66.php' , $plugins );
         if ( false !== $key ) unset( $plugins[$key] );
      }

     return $plugins;
 }
```

I have also tried to us plugin organizer but it is not helping to **NOT** activate a certain plugin on a SINGLE PAGE.

BTW, if anyone got a code that can only activate certain plugins such as Contact form no 7 by tracing their shortcode on a post/page that will be brilliant! 
Something like if x page/post has a shortcode that contains 'contact form no 7' then activate Contact form no 7 plugin, else, do not activate.

Anyway, at this stage, an easy to go solution will do :)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you start by explaining _why_ you’d want this? I don’t think trying to enable/disable plugins all the time is a good idea to begin with.

Comment: My guess is that he wants to try to minimize the load of scripts - So only load CF7s scripts if there is a contact form on that page. - but deactivating it all together and activating them again, seems like a bad idea. - imagine if there is more than one user on the website - user A tells the DB to deactivate CF7, and user B tells the DB to activate it. Seems troublesome

Comment: But loading a script if a shortcode is present can be done, and has been answered on the sister site : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/191512/82677

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I need to deactivate the plugins you see on the bottom left of the screen on this page: https://www.worldpronet.com/123/

Comment: Hi Stender, Thanks for the link, I have checked it and it's a good start but it's not quite answering my question because there it's like a specific subject and not relevant to plugins. And at the moment I need a solution for global plugin deactivation and not a shortcode based plugin. My suggestion was to have a solution for each case.

Answer (score 2):

"BTW, if anyone got a code that can only activate certain plugins such as Contact form no 7 by tracing their shortcode on a post/page that will be brilliant! Something like if x page/post has a shortcode that contains 'contact form no 7' then activate Contact form no 7 plugin, else, do not activate." - **This is not possible.** Reading the source code wp-blog-header.php should make this clear.

```
$wp_did_header = true;

// Load the WordPress library.
require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-load.php' );

// Set up the WordPress query.
wp();

// Load the theme template.
require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );
```

Plugins are loaded by wp-settings.php which is loaded by wp-load.php. The post content of a request is retrieved from the database by WP::query_posts() which is called by the function wp(). So, plugins are already loaded before the post content is even retrieved from the database.

**Where did you put the code**:

add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'lg_disable_cart66_plugin' );

**This cannot be put in a regular plugin** since it must execute **BEFORE** plugins are loaded. (You cannot tell a plugin not to load in code that is already loaded.) It also cannot be put in functions.php since functions.php is loaded **AFTER** plugins are loaded. Did you read the comment about mu-plugins? "must use" plugins are loaded before regular plugins. All of this can be found in wp-settings.php - I highly recommend reading it - it is an easy read and you will understand how WordPress initializes itself.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. This is definitely one of the most professional answers I've read here.
I did put the code in the mu-plugins directory as directed.
From what I understand this directory works before the plugins are running. So can the shortcodes be scanned within this directory before the plugins come into action?
Anyway, the current code didn't help me because it limits the plugin to work on a single page and in my case, I need the plugin NOT to work on a single page because my plugins are global (member registration&login, Google translate, privacy policy and scroll up).

Comment: "So can the shortcodes be scanned within this directory before the plugins come into action?" -  Yes, but this means you must retrieve the post content for the posts that will be displayed before WordPress has even parsed the request. In other words you would need to essentially do the query processing out of order. It is now your responsibility to parse the request and do the SQL query and WordPress will duplicate this effort again later. This is probably not a good idea - it is not easy to do and will not be efficient because of the duplication of code.

Comment: "I need the plugin NOT to work on a single page because my plugins are global (member registration&login" - The filter 'option_active_plugins' lets you edit the list of active plugins. You can write your own conditions to conditionally select which plugins will be omitted from this list. Unfortunately, these conditions must be based on the raw URL since at this point in time WordPress has not yet parsed the URL and the matching posts/pages are not yet known..

Comment: Thanks, Magenta Cuda. Can you please share with me a sample code for let's say: URL  www.worldpronet.com/123/Electric cigarettes China-Israel (Page Id 11269) plugin name to be omitted: to-top,  using The filter 'option_active_plugins'?