# Disable a Wordpress Plugin on Specific Admin URLs

Tags: wordpress, plugins

There are two conflicting plugins on my site:

1. Payment Forms for Paystack
2. Formidable Forms

Is there a way to disable Payment Forms for Paystack WP plugin only on the entry pages for my formidable form: `site.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=formidable-entries&frm_action=edit&id=x` where `x= any positive number from 1 to infinity` ?

When I disable the Paystack plugin, I can view the form entries of Formidable. But when enabled, it causes an error that scrambles all the fields.

I tried the solution (by @mainpart) of a similar question to no avail:
[Wordpress Disable Plugin on Specific Pages/Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774424/wordpress-disable-plugin-on-specific-pages-posts)

```php
 add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'lg_disable_ps_plugin' );

 function lg_disable_ps_plugin($plugins){

      if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'formidable-entries') === FALSE AND strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/wp-admin/') === FALSE) {
         $key = array_search( 'payment-forms-for-paystack/paystack-forms.php' , $plugins );
         if ( false !== $key ) unset( $plugins[$key] );
      }

     return $plugins;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to resolve it:

1. I installed and activated Plugin Organizer WP Plugin
2. Used Settings:

   - Fuzzy URL matching - ON
   - Ignore URL Protocol - ON
   - Ignore URL argument - ON
   - Auto trailing slash - ON
   - **Selective Plugin Loading - ON (very important)**
   - **Selective Admin Plugin Loading - ON (very important)**
3. Created a new plugin filter with the permalink `http://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=formidable-entries`
4. Checked "Also Affect Children" in the plugin filter page
5. Disabled Payment Forms for Paystack in the list of plugins in the filter page
6. Saved and that solved it for me

This took me weeks of almost losing my mind! Hopefully the above helps others